# Representing an item in an inventory

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and I need some advice from the more experienced Neo4j developers.

In which situation does it makes sense for an inventory system to represent individual items as a path through their properties instead of a node with the same properties?

In order to make my self clear:
Let's say we have a eyeglass lens. This item has properties like it's SPHERE power it's CYLINDER power and an AXIS, among others.
There is a finite set of SPHERE powers but also of CYLINDER power and AXIS. The combination of those makes an item (lens). 
Does it make sense to represent a lens like this:

```
MATCH (lens:Lens)-[:-2.00]-(sph:Sphere:{power:'-2.00'})-[:-0.50]-(cyl:Cylinder{power:'-0.50'})-[:90]-(ax:Axis{degree:'90'})
RETURN lens.brand_name, lens.price
```

Please note that the above item(lens) can be available from different manufacturers and with different brand names and list prices so "lens" will represent all individual brands that can match with the above query and will have as properties the brand name and price, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a piece of data ("SPHERE").  When should it be a property of the lens node, and when should it be its own node, via relation?

- Do you need to relate multiple lenses to the same sphere?  This argues it should be its own node, so that multiple lenses can link to the same sphere.
- Do you need to assert extra properties about the sphere value?  (Like who measured it, or when?)  This argues you should make it a separate node.
- Do you need to store properties about the relationship?   If the relationship is any more complicated than simple "HAS A" you might want a relationship between two nodes, so you can store properties on the relationship.

Any of those cases would argue you should store that piece of data as a separate node, and then relate it by relationship.

ON THE OTHER HAND, if it's a simple primitive data type (float), with a simple "HAS-A" relationship to the parent (i.e. a lens HAS-A sphere measurement) and you have no need for extra metadata, then it should be a node property.

I'm not an optometrist but I think this latter situation is your case, I'm just trying to give you a more general answer.  "Sphere" should probably be a node property, but the cases above are how to think about the issue more generally for future data items.

Comment: So, due to the fact that I need to be able to get all kinds of information related to a lenses individual properties(Sphere, Cylinder, etc) I think it will be a good plan to represent it as a set of individual nodes connected with relationships.

Answer (score 1):

In your special domain, with finite ranges and discrete values for each of the parameters, it absolutely makes sense to model the properties of a lens as value nodes. The resulting index graph seems not to be too large, and quite balanced (no supernodes).